# VideoWriter Error in OpenCv

Tags: c++, opencv

```
#include<sstream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    VideoCapture cap("test2.mp4");
    assert(cap.isOpened());

    cap>>prev;


    VideoWriter outputVideo; 

    if (!outputVideo.isOpened())outputVideo.open("compare.mp4" , CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D'), 24,cvSize(cur.rows, cur.cols*2+10), true); 

    outputVideo<< prev;

    while(true) {



        stringstream ss;

        string name = "cropped_";
        string type = ".jpg";

        ss<<name<<(chk)<<type;

        string filename = ss.str();
        ss.str("");

        imwrite(filename, canvas);

        outputVideo<< canvas;
        prev = cur.clone();//cur.copyTo(prev);
        prev_ref = cur_ref.clone();//cur.copyTo(prev);

        cur_grey.copyTo(prev_grey);

        cout << "Frame: " << k << "/" << max_frames << " - good optical flow: " << prev_corner2.size() << endl;
        k++;

}
```

Question:It is a small description of my code.Now when I try to write my canvas(variable of type Mat in OpenCV) for creating a video.It's giving an error.Even if I try for .avi file or .mp4 file it doesn't write/create a video.Please help me out.It shows an error "[mp4 @ 0xa0aac0] Tag XVID/0x44495658 incompatible with output codec id '13' error ".I am using ubuntu 14.04 with intel core processor-i5

Comment: Maybe you should state the error you get.

Comment: And maybe mention what operating system you're running.

Comment: I have made the changes in the question.If you could help me out that would be very thankful of you